# wpf make relative designing without hardcoding even a sindle width or height

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Can anybody help how to make the wpf optimized design meaning if we stretch the window all the controls inside should be relatively expand with the parent controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is probably too vague and likely will end up being either closed or you'll be asked to clarify. But the layout piece that you probably want to focus on if you want your controls to grow/shrink with their parents is the [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx). If you use star-based sizing for the columns/rows, things will grow/shrink relative to each other and to the parent. I suggest you read up on that concept along with the other [layout concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx).